# iOS App development

Tags: c++, ios, macos

I'm planning to start on programming apps for iOS. But I have a couple questions i'm struggling with. I looked up a few sdk's for ios development on windows and found Marmalade. I found this interesting since I program in C++. But the thing is, I don't want to start on making games. I want to make informative apps about games. like an 'information browser about champions(league of legends) or items in a particular game. it looks like marmalade is for games. My sister has a macbook pro so I tried out Xcode but I can't prgram in objective-c. I'm willing to learn it if you think thats the best thing to do. would you guys recommend me to download/install OSX on my windows pc? could you guys please help me out. i'm already struggling for 2 days with this. trying everything out etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Go to amazon, order a book about iOS development, read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning Objective-C is an absolute minimum for iOS development. You really will be needing a Mac to develop on, but if you want to learn Objective-C before picking up a Mac then install a copy of Linux; gcc will compile Objective-C. Once you have a Mac you'll have free access to XCode, which includes amongst other things an iPhone / iPad simulator.